# Set a timer with actions on google

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

Hi I'm currently working on an app for google home / google Assistant

I use dialogflow and after my intent I want to ask the user if I should set a timer for him. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to the timer/alarm on the Google Home or Google Assistant.

In some cases, you can use [Notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications) to do what you want, but these aren't available on the Google Home yet.