# How do you delay a follow up intent in dialogflow?

Tags: android-intent, dialogflow-es, chatbot

Completely new to creating an application for Google Home. What I'm trying to achieve and I'm not even sure if it's possible:

> "Run [name] app"
>
> *"Running [name] app now"* - This sets a 5 minute timer in the intent so there's a delay in the follow up intent.

Once the 5 minute timer finishes that's set in the first intent, it triggers the follow up intent.

> "Are you ok?"
>
> "Yes" - Resets the timer back to 5 minutes again. Once the 5 minutes is done, it asks the question again. It will keep on doing it until the app is ultimately stopped.
>
> "No" or "..." (No Response) - [placeholder action]

I'm just wondering if this idea is possible at all with the tools available in Dialogflow? I'm kind of lost on how to set a timer in the background after running the app initially. I saw from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857848/set-a-timer-with-actions-on-google) that I don't have access to the timer/alarm. Is there a way around this with what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow is intended to build a conversational UI, so there is nothing specific to Dialogflow that lets you delay triggering an Intent.

However, the platform you're working on may have some way to do so. So if you're calling Dialogflow from an Android app (not through the Google Assistant) for example, you can use Android's facilities to set the timer and trigger the Dialogflow event at that time.